# What are the most important algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, theory

Christoph Koutschan has set up [an interesting survey](http://www.risc.jku.at/people/ckoutsch/stuff/e_algorithms.html) that tries to identify the most important algorithms "in the world". Since one of the criteria is that "the algorithm has to be widely used" I though that extending the survey to the huge group of users at Stack Overflow would be a natural thing to do.

So, what do you think? Which algorithms deserve a place in the Algorithm Hall of Fame?

Comment: Is "data compression" really an algorithm?

Comment: I think your link already does a good job, and there's no point hoping for "better" answers — beyond this point, it's too subjective, and answers will vary with the field one works in. The most general ideas — binary search, branch-and-bound, divide-and-conquer, dynamic programming, Newton's method / gradient descent, the common graph search algorithms, etc. — will be represented everywhere, so much so that they are almost meta-algorithms.

Comment: There's also so much overlap between ideas that it's pointless "ranking" algorithms as 'most important'. For instance, Newton's method and gradient descent are arguably "morally" equivalent (and EM is also close), Buchberger's amazing algorithm is Euclidean algorithm + Gaussian elimination, SVD is closely related to the latter, etc.

Comment: This question is like "whats the best carpentry tool".  To which the only real answer is "all of them".

Comment: Practitioners and scientists may have different points of view about what is an "important" algorithm. For example I don't see in the link any producer-consumer-locking way of understanding life

Comment: Sorting, hashing, generic search, folding/unfolding.

Answer (score 3):

I somewhat like this algorithm:

1. Write code.
2. Test code. If buggy, go to step 3. If not, go to step 4.
3. Rewrite code, then go back to step 2.
4. Get somebody else to test your code. If they discover any bugs, return to step 3, otherwise go to step 5.
5. Congratulations, your code has no obvious bugs! Now you wait for a user to stumble upon a hidden one, in which case you return to step 3 once again unless you're lucky and are no longer providing support for the code in question.

Comment: 6. Deliver -> 7. Mantain (ie. GOTO 1)

Comment: @belisarius: yeah, modified #5 a bit.

Comment: + 1, but I would change in 5. "unless your are lucky and ..." :)

Comment: Now is perfect. go deliver and mantain your answer ... Wait ... you are lucky! ... The thread has been closed :*

Answer (score 0):

I'd say binary search since it's usually the first algorithm people learn. And the RSA encryption algorithms are pretty important.

Answer (score 0):

Hashing, since it's the basis for so much in security, data structures, etc.  Hashing algorithms have generated a lot of Ph.D. dissertations.